# python import requests not working

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm having trouble getting import requests to work. It's working when I use terminal, but I'm trying to accomplish the same thing on my website now. It is a site hosted on hostgator, the rest of my python is working correctly. What's odd is I can import json and that works just fine, but not requests. Essentially the site stops processing at the import. Any ideas?

Here's my code below

```html
print('<br/>')
print('import sys')
import sys
print('<br/>')
print(sys.modules)

print('<br/>')
print('import platform')
import platform
print('<br/>')
print(sys.modules)

print('<br/>')
print('import json')
import json
print('<br/>')
print(sys.modules)

print('<br/>')
print('import requests')
import requests
print('<br/>')
print(sys.modules)
```

The output of the code is following:

import sys

{'copy_reg': , 'encodings': , 'site': , '**builtin**': , '**main**': , 'encodings.encodings': None, 'abc': , 'posixpath': , 'errno': , 'encodings.codecs': None, '_abcoll': , 'types': , '_codecs': , '_warnings': , 'genericpath': , 'stat': , 'zipimport': , 'encodings.**builtin**': None, 'warnings': , 'UserDict': , 'encodings.ascii': , 'sys': , 'pwd': , 'codecs': , 'os.path': , 'signal': , 'linecache': , 'posix': , 'encodings.aliases': , 'exceptions': , 'abrt_exception_handler': , 'os': }

import platform

{'copy_reg': , 'sre_compile': , '_sre': , 'encodings': , 'site': , '**builtin**': , '**main**': , 'encodings.encodings': None, 'abc': , 'posixpath': , 're': , 'errno': , 'encodings.codecs': None, 'sre_constants': , 'platform': , '_abcoll': , 'types': , '_codecs': , '_warnings': , 'genericpath': , 'stat': , 'zipimport': , 'encodings.**builtin**': None, 'string': , 'warnings': , 'UserDict': , 'encodings.ascii': , 'sys': , 'pwd': , 'codecs': , 'os.path': , 'strop': , 'signal': , 'linecache': , 'posix': , 'encodings.aliases': , 'exceptions': , 'sre_parse': , 'abrt_exception_handler': , 'os': }

import json

{'json.decoder': , 'copy_reg': , 'sre_compile': , '_sre': , 'encodings': , 'site': , '**builtin**': , '**main**': , 'encodings.encodings': None, 'json.math': None, 'json.sre_constants': None, 'json.sre_compile': None, 'abc': , 'posixpath': , 're': , 'errno': , '_json': , 'encodings.codecs': None, 'sre_constants': , 'platform': , 'json': , '_abcoll': , 'types': , '_codecs': , '_warnings': , 'math': , 'json._json': None, 'genericpath': , 'stat': , 'zipimport': , 'encodings.**builtin**': None, 'string': , 'warnings': , 'UserDict': , 'encodings.ascii': , 'json.json': None, 'json.sys': None, 'sys': , 'pwd': , 'codecs': , 'json.encoder': , 'os.path': , 'strop': , 'json.re': None, 'signal': , 'json.scanner': , 'linecache': , 'json.sre_parse': None, 'posix': , 'encodings.aliases': , 'exceptions': , 'sre_parse': , 'abrt_exception_handler': , 'os': }

import requests

Comment: Is the `requests` module installed on your host?  The other modules are builtins, but requests is not.

Comment: it would appear not. What is confusing me is neither was the json module, but that seemed to work fine?

Comment: As I said, the other modules you import (including json) are *built in* to Python.  Requests is a third-party module that you must install yourself.

Comment: you could install the requests module with `pip install requests` check [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/#install)